# .NET Maui Map Pin Example

Tags: geolocation, maui

I'm not sure this is actually possible, but I can't seem to find an example so maybe not. Just trying to display location pins on the map at certain long/lat coordinates i have available. Can anyone link an example?

Comment: MAUI does not currently have a native map control

Comment: In .NET 7 there is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found it on the Microsoft Page not sure why Google didn't pick it up in my search :D

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0

```
Map map = new Map
{
  ...
};

Pin pin = new Pin
{
  Label = "Santa Cruz",
  Address = "The city with a boardwalk",
  Type = PinType.Place,
  Location = new Location(36.9628066, -122.0194722)
};
map.Pins.Add(pin);
```

Comment: I flagged this for [deletion](/help/deleted-answers) because it consists almost entirely of a link. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is [useful without it](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259): add context around the link so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part in case the linked page is unavailable. If you [edit] this answer to add more once it is deleted, please flag it for moderator attention so that it can be un-deleted.